# Set Default value for a django ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelchoicefield

I need to set a default value for `ModelChoiceField`

The value is being sent from my `views.py`.

I've looked for some other similar questions but it didn't really help as it was all about `ChoiceField` with `choices` not a `ModelChoiceField` with `queryset`

**views.py**

```py
def edit_package(request, pk):
    current_package = get_object_or_404(models.Package, pk=pk)
    edit_package_form = forms.EditPackageForm(request.POST, name=current_package.package_name,
                                              teacher=current_package.package_teacher_name,
                                              level=current_package.package_level,
                                              subject=current_package.package_subject,
                                              price=current_package.package_price)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if edit_package_form.is_valid():
            pass
        else:
            edit_package_form = forms.EditPackageForm(request.POST, name=current_package.package_name,
                                                      teacher=current_package.package_teacher_name,
                                                      level=current_package.package_level,
                                                      subject=current_package.package_subject,
                                                      price=current_package.package_price)
    context = {
        'current_package': current_package,
        'edit_package_form': edit_package_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'edit_package.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class EditPackageForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_name = kwargs.pop("name")  
        current_teacher = kwargs.pop("teacher")  
        current_level = kwargs.pop("level")  
        current_subject = kwargs.pop("subject")  
        current_price = kwargs.pop("price")  

        super(EditPackageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['package_name'] = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': current_name}))
        self.fields['teacher_name'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Teacher.objects.all(),
                                                             initial=current_teacher,
                                                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                                             required=False)
        self.fields['level_name'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Level.objects.all(),
                                                           initial=current_level,
                                                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                                           required=False)
        self.fields['subject_name'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Subject.objects.all(),
                                                             initial=current_subject,
                                                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                                             required=False)
        self.fields['package_price'] = forms.IntegerField(
            widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value': current_price}))
```

And that is how it looks, `TextInput` and `NumberInput` have the default value, but the `initial` didn't work with `ModelChoiceField`

[image: Screen_shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example in the ModelChoiceField for the name of the teacher, you are sending a name from the view, what is wrong, since you must send the teacher's id to the form and that id assign it in initial. The same should be done with the rest.

```
edit_package_form = forms.EditPackageForm(request.POST, name=current_package.package_name,
                                          teacher=current_package.package_teacher_id,
                                          level=current_package.package_level_id,
                                          subject=current_package.package_subject_id,
                                          price=current_package.package_price)
```